# How to print out a string with zero-padding?

Tags: java, string, format, printf

I have to print out a string ("01" for example) with zeros to the left of the number, so that in total there are 6 characters printed out. For example, a string of value "01" should be printed out as "000001".

I have searched for ways to do this, but using various forms of printf I have only been able to print it with the right amount of spacing, but the spaces are not occupied by zeros.

Here's what I've tried:

```
String id = "01";
System.out.printf("%6s", id);
```

Which outputs:

```
     1
```

I read that adding a 0 before the 6 and after the % should add the zeros in the spots I want them but it throws run-time errors.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to integer and then do the formatting.

```
String id = "01";
int i = Integer.parseInt(id);
System.out.printf("%06d", i);
```

Output:

```
000001
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to convert it from a String because of how I have to use it later, but I suppose I will just have to work around that. Thank you for the quick response.